# Cursor getInt return negative value

Tags: android, sql, integer

at first I want to notice that english isn't my native language, whatever I hope we won't have missunderstaning

I write simple application on Android, and found an issue, also solved it, but anyway I want to understand why it was.

I created an sql table:

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE_ENTRIES = " CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_ENTRIES + " ( " + KEY_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, "
            + " content " + " TEXT, "
            + " title" + " TEXT, "
            + " image " + " TEXT, "
            + " date " + " INTEGER, " + ")";
```

And put an data into it this way:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mStorage.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues tempValues = new ContentValues();
tempValues.put("id", entry.id);
tempValues.put("content", entry.content);
tempValues.put("title", entry.title);
tempValues.put("image", entry.image);
tempValues.put("date", entry.date);  // int date; I use Unix time
db.insert(contentType, null, tempValues);
```

Now.. everything is ok, I verified using [this application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=oliver.ehrenmueller.dbadmin&hl=en), that stored values are allright.

Nevertheless when I try to get the date value using `cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"))` I'm getting 1) wrong value 2) its negative ( like -1004124 )

So, I tried to replace it with getLong and voila! I get my unix time.

The question is - whats wrong with getInt here?

Comment: What is the value you're saving to that field?

Comment: @Szymon I'm entering unix time, as I can know from wiki its 1387233645 right now, so but it almost less than twice from 2^32-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're using unixtime (seconds since epoch) and not e.g. Java system time (milliseconds since epoch)?

For example, unixtime `1387233645` fits well in a 32-bit int.

However, millisecond stamp `1387233645000` is too large for 32 bits. In hex it's `0x142fd9191c8`. Taking the bottom 32 bits leaves us with `0xfd9191c8` which is `-40791608` in decimal when interpreted as a Java `int` i.e. signed two's complement 32-bit integer.

Comment: Well, you are right. I rechecked the values and I realy store it in milliseconds. Fail :D
Also I didnt checked my object type - its `long` and not `int` like I wrote in the question

Answer (score 0):

The value you entered into that database field must be greater than 2^31-1, ie. the max `int` positive value. As `int` type is a signed integer, if the left-most bit (position 32) is 1, this value is interpreted as negative.

When you load the value as `long`, all bits are interpreted differently to mean a positive long number.